# Is there a good introduction to memory barriers?

Tags: java, concurrency, memory-barriers

I'm looking for a good online introduction to memory barriers and the usual pitfalls in Java code:

- Using `synchronized` too often or not often enough
- When to use `volatile` and `final`
- Double checked locking
- etc.

I'd be especially interested in code which shows the behavior and/or examples how to solve common problems (like creating a map that several threads can access and where values are added lazily).

Comment: Does it have to be online? I would definitely recommend getting [JCiP](http://jcip.net/) in the long run if you haven't so far...

Answer (score 5):

You might find [this article](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/memory-barriersfences.html) by Martin Thomson very helpful.

Comment: +1 It doesn't answer most of my questions but I like it since it's the first explanation of memory barriers that I could understand without reading it several times!

Answer (score 3):

I know you said online, but [Java Concurrency In Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) is *the* java concurrency guide these days.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know more about this from a CPU perspective (what assembler code is generated and how the JVM can optimize the byte code), this article might be interesting: [Memory Barriers and JVM Concurrency](http://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency) (InfoQ)